# Handling an OnClick event of a checkbox

Tags: c++, com, atl, bho, mshtml

I'm trying to handle click events of a checkbox control from a BHO.

Here is my code:

```
void STDMETHODCALLTYPE CMyBHO::OnDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *pvarURL)
{
    // ...

    InitPage(pDocument);
}

void CMyBHO::InitPage(IHTMLDocument2 *pDocument)
{
    CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument3> document3 = pDocument;

    CComPtr<IHTMLElement> elementCheckbox;
    document3->getElementById(CComBSTR(L"checkbox_id_here"), &elementCheckbox);
    if(!elementCheckbox)
        return;

    if(!m_fCheckboxAdvised)
    {
        // Register to sink events from HTMLDocumentEvents2.
        hr = IHTMLElementEvents2Impl::DispEventAdvise(elementCheckbox);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            m_fCheckboxAdvised = TRUE;
        else
            ATLASSERT(0); // FAILS HERE, hr = 0x80040200
    }
}
```

Header file:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyBHO :
    /*...*/
    public IDispEventImpl<1, CMyBHO, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1>,
    public IDispEventImpl<2, CMyBHO, &DIID_HTMLElementEvents2, &LIBID_MSHTML, 4, 0>
{
    typedef IDispEventImpl<1, CMyBHO, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1> IDWebBrowserEvents2Impl;
    typedef IDispEventImpl<2, CMyBHO, &DIID_HTMLElementEvents2, &LIBID_MSHTML, 4, 0> IHTMLElementEvents2Impl;

public:

    /*...*/

    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CMyBHO)
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete)
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(2, DIID_HTMLElementEvents2, DISPID_HTMLELEMENTEVENTS2_ONCLICK, OnMouseClick)
    END_SINK_MAP()

public:
    STDMETHOD(SetSite)(IUnknown *pUnkSite);

    // DWebBrowserEvents2
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *pvarURL);

    // HTMLDocumentEvents2
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnMouseClick(IHTMLEventObj *eventObj);

    /*...*/
};
```

`DispEventAdvise` fails with hr = `0x80040200`. What am I doing wrong?

Also, when should I call `DispEventUnadvise`?

Comment: HTML elements don't implement connection ponits, so you have `CONNECT_E_NOCONNECTION` failure. Instead, you need to implement `IDispatch` on your object and assign the interface pointer to `onclick` property of the HTML element. You will get `IDispatch::Invoke` call on the event.

Comment: @RomanR., thank you for the comment. I'm not very experienced with BHOs and/or ATL. It would be very helpful if you could provide a minimal example, or a link with more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RomanR. HTML elements do too implement connection points. They are somewhat inconvenient to use though, because different kinds of elements accept different source interfaces: there's no single sink you can advise to all of them. E.g. `<input type="checkbox">` is represented by `HTMLInputElement` coclass which supports the following source interfaces: `HTMLInputTextElementEvents`, `HTMLInputTextElementEvents2`, `HTMLOptionButtonElementEvents`, `HTMLButtonElementEvents` - but **not** `HTMLElementEvents2` the OP is trying to sink.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks, I stand corrected here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks, that's very interesting. So, can I use each of the above to capture click events? Also, an important question - when should I call the `DispEventUnadvise` function?

Comment: Yes, all four expose onclick event; you can sink any of them. Note that for two of them, the event comes with `IHTMLEventObj*` parameter, while for the other two there's no parameter; see `mshtml.idl` in Windows SDK `include` directory for details. You may or may not care. You don't need to call `DispEventUnadvise` - when the page is unloaded, elements will unilaterally unadvise all sinks before being destroyed. Or at least, that's how it worked in IE6, which was still new and shiny when I last dealt with this stuff.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, your info helps a lot, thanks. If I don't need to call `DispEventUnadvise`, is there a way to know whether a control was already "advised"? IE doesn't notify upon refreshes, so I'm using a timer. I need to know whether the control I found with `getElementById` was already handled. P.S. sorry if that's too much off-topic. Should I create a new question?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `DownloadBegin` and `DownloadComplete` events still fire on refresh - perhaps you could use those (if you see `DownloadBegin` without a preceding `BeforeNavigate2`, a refresh is taking place). Or, you could save the interface pointer from previous `getElementById` call, and see if the new call returns the same element.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, `DownloadBegin` and `DownloadComplete` capture AJAX requests, too.

Comment: @Paul Store your advised elements in a vector or list. When polling via timer, you may be able to check if an element is in the list, using IsSameObject. Polling via timer is usefull, even in the absence of refresh. Lot of pages do weird things to the DOM at 'random' moments.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the connection point you request, hence the `CONNECT_E_NOCONNECTION` failure.

Instead of implementing a connection point client for HTML elements with a multitude of interfaces, you might prefer an alternate route and implement IDispatch on your event sink object, and then assign the interface pointer to `onclick` property of the HTML element. You will get `IDispatch::Invoke` call on the event.

Here is a code snippet for you for creating an instance of suitable `IDispatch` implemetnation, and setting `onresize` property via C++ code:

```
CComPtr<IHTMLElement> pBodyElementA;
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pDocument->get_body(&pBodyElementA));
CComPtr<IDispatch> pSinkDispatch;
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(CDispatchEventSink::CreateInstance(&pSinkDispatch));
CComVariant vValue = pSinkDispatch;
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(reinterpret_cast<CComPtr<IDispatch>&>(pBodyElementA).
    PutPropertyByName(L"onresize", &vValue));
```

`CDispatchEventSink` class is [here](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/DispEventSample03/MainDialog.h#L55), and you will find full sample project there as well (also, [SVN](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/DispEventSample03/) link).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. **1.** I ended up implementing @IgorTandetnik's suggestion, using `HTMLInputTextElementEvents2`, and it works as expected. **2.** The example you have specified has the same limitation that I'm experiencing: it doesn't handle page refreshes. Upon a refresh, the `onresize` hook is lost as `OnExplorer2DocumentComplete` is not being called.

Comment: You might be able to see page refreshes on web browser events (around `DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2` in your code). I would put tracing code to see all events you are getting to see if there is anything useful there.

Comment: I tried that, but couldn't come up with anything relevant. It's so frustrating how such a basic thing doesn't have a straightforward solution. For my case, knowing when the checkbox is going away (along with the page, probably) will be good enough. I've created [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21110352/2604492) about it.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. When you assign to `onclick` property (or `onresize`, or similar), you are fighting with the script on the page for it. Your assignment may overwrite the handler that the script installed, breaking the page. Or the script may assign its handler later and overwrite yours, breaking your BHO. If you want to go down that route, use `attachEvent` or `addEventListener` methods - these can add more than one handler for the same event.